# PyQt5 - Unexpected behaviour of QTreeView when a QSortFilterProxyModel is set as model

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I am developing an application with PyQt5 5.7.1 on Python 3.5. I use a QTreeView to display some data with a hierachy. I would like to be able to filter this data, so I used a QSortFilterProxy model.

```
self.model = CustomTreeModel(data)
self.proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel(self.model)
self.ui.treeView.setModel(self.proxy)
```

This gives a strange behaviour:
By default, the treeView is collapsed. If I expand any item which is not the first one, and then click on any of its children, the first item of the treeView gets expanded (it shouldn't). Actually, whenever I click on any item which is not first level (a child of the root item), the first child of the root item gets expanded.

I thought there was an issue with my model, but if I don't use QSortFilterProxy model, like this :

```
self.model = CustomTreeModel(data)
self.ui.treeView.setModel(self.model)
```

The treeView behaves as expected, the first element doesn't expand when it shouldn't.

It seems to me that this is a bug in PyQt5, but I didn't find any information about it on the Internet. On the contrary, there are some examples of using QSortFilterProxyModel with a QTreeView and nobody seems to report such issue. So is it really a bug in PyQt or am I missing something ?

Here is a demo code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractItemModel, QModelIndex, Qt

class CustomTreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    # Based on http://trevorius.com/scrapbook/uncategorized/pyqt-custom-abstractitemmodel/    

    def __init__(self, headerData, nodes):  
        QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self)  
        self._headerData = headerData
        self._root = CustomNode(None)
        for node in nodes:
            self._root.addChild(node)

    def addChild(self, in_node, in_parent=QModelIndex()):  
        if not in_parent or not in_parent.isValid():  
            parent = self._root  
        else:  
            parent = in_parent.internalPointer()  
        parent.addChild(in_node)

    def index(self, in_row, in_column, in_parent=QModelIndex()):  
        if not in_parent.isValid():  
            parent = self._root  
        else:  
            parent = in_parent.internalPointer()        
        if not QAbstractItemModel.hasIndex(self, in_row, in_column, in_parent):  
            return QModelIndex()  

        child = parent.child(in_row)  
        if child:  
            return QAbstractItemModel.createIndex(self, in_row, in_column, child)  
        else:  
            return QModelIndex()  

    def rowCount(self, in_index=QModelIndex()):  
        if in_index.isValid():  
            return in_index.internalPointer().childCount()  
        return self._root.childCount()  

    def child(self, row, index):
        if index.isValid():
            c = index.internalPointer().child(row)
            return QAbstractItemModel.createIndex(self, row, 0, c)
        return QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, in_index):  
        if in_index.isValid():  
            p = in_index.internalPointer().parent()  
            if p:  
                return QAbstractItemModel.createIndex(self, p.row(),0,p)  
        return QModelIndex()  

    def columnCount(self, in_index):  
        if in_index.isValid():  
            return in_index.internalPointer().columnCount()  
        return self._root.columnCount()  

    def data(self, in_index, role):  
        if not in_index.isValid():  
            return None  
        node = in_index.internalPointer()  
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:  
            return node.data(in_index.column())
        return None

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if (section < 0) or (section > self.columnCount(QModelIndex())):
            return None
        if (orientation == Qt.Horizontal) and (role == Qt.DisplayRole):
            return self._headerData[section]
        return None

class CustomNode(object):
    def __init__(self, in_data):  
        self._data = in_data  
        if type(in_data) == tuple:  
            self._data = list(in_data)  
        if type(in_data) == str  or not hasattr(in_data, '__getitem__'):  
            self._data = [in_data]  

        self._columncount = len(self._data)  
        self._children = []  
        self._parent = None  
        self._row = 0

    def data(self, in_column):  
        if in_column >= 0 and in_column < len(self._data):  
            return self._data[in_column]
        return None

    def columnCount(self):  
        return self._columncount  

    def childCount(self):  
        return len(self._children)  

    def child(self, in_row):  
        if in_row >= 0 and in_row < self.childCount():  
            return self._children[in_row]
        return None

    def parent(self):  
        return self._parent  

    def row(self):  
        return self._row  

    def addChild(self, in_child):  
        in_child._parent = self
        in_child._row = len(self._children)  
        self._children.append(in_child)  
        self._columncount = max(in_child.columnCount(), self._columncount)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel  
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeView

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    header = ['Food']

    fruits = CustomNode(['Fruit'])
    fruits.addChild(CustomNode(['Apple']))
    fruits.addChild(CustomNode(['Banana']))
    fruits.addChild(CustomNode(['Orange']))
    vegetables = CustomNode(['Vegetables'])
    vegetables.addChild(CustomNode(['Carott']))
    vegetables.addChild(CustomNode(['Potato']))
    meat = CustomNode(['Meat'])
    meat.addChild(CustomNode(['Beef']))
    meat.addChild(CustomNode(['Chicken']))
    meat.addChild(CustomNode(['Pork']))

    nodes = [fruits, vegetables, meat]

    v = QTreeView()
    model = CustomTreeModel(header, nodes)
    proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel()
    proxy.setSourceModel(model)
    v.setModel(proxy)
    v.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```